# Update Trigger, set value for the inserted data SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger, if update is assigning a user. And we have not set the value before.

I have this but server doesn't like it.... I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

on the 'set' line.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgIssueAcknowledged 
ON  dbo.hdIssues
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    If (select inserted.AssignedToUserID from inserted) IS NULL 
    begin
        return
    end

    If (select inserted.AssignedToUserID from inserted) = 0
    begin
        return
    end

    If (select inserted.AcknowledgeDate from inserted) IS NULL
    begin
      set inserted.AcknowledgeDate = GETDATE ( );
    end
END 
GO
```

Comment: Typo in `AcknoledgeDate`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your trigger has many issues, it doesn't use the real table you want to update, it assumes only one row is modified every time, and the logic with the `RETURN` is too weird.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgIssueAcknowledged 
ON  dbo.hdIssues
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE A
SET A.AcknowledgeDate = GETDATE()
FROM dbo.hdIssues A
INNER JOIN INSERTED I
    ON A.TheKeyOfTheTable = I.TheKeyOfTheTable 
WHERE A.AcknowledgeDate IS NULL
AND ( A.AssignedToUserID <> 0 AND A.AssignedToUserID IS NOT NULL)

END
```

Comment: I've never done it before, I am NOT assuming one row.  The return was a sample I had found on the interwebs, it seem ok to me (ie if it is null I don't want to do anything else, don't need to test anything else).

Comment: @BrianHanf It does assumes one row even if you haven't noticed it. Everyone of your if's is assuming only one row: `If (select inserted.AssignedToUserID from inserted) IS NULL`

Comment: I think I need to change 'AND A.AssignedToUserID <> 0' to 'AND A.AssignedToUserID > 0' but this looks really promising.

Comment: I added a test for IS NOT NULL because AssignedTOUserID is a nullable field.

Comment: @BrianHanf That change is unnecesary, since if the `A.AssignedToUserID <> 0` condition is true, it means that it's not null

Comment: I'm pretty sure that null is both greater and less than zero when we test in SQL for it. - [This is a MySQL article, maybe it doesn't apply to MS SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/)

Comment: @BrianHanf Well, you are actually pretty wrong about that in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Could it perhaps be the spelling mistake?

inserted.AcknoledgeDate

looks like it is missing "w"

should be

inserted.AcknowledgeDate

Comment: typing mistake in the tranfer to SO

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all inserted is a virtual table, so if you want to update one of the columns, you need to do an UPDATE.

```
UPDATE inserted
 set AcknowledgeDate = GETDATE ( )
WHERE AcknowledgeDate  IS NULL;
```

But second of all, why do you want to update the value in the inserted table in an AFTER UPDATE trigger?   What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgIssueAcknowledged ON dbo.hdIssues
        AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
    AS
        BEGIN               
            SET NOCOUNT ON;             
            BEGIN TRY

                DECLARE @INSERTCOUNT INT
                DECLARE @DELETECOUNT INT
                SET @INSERTCOUNT = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                     FROM   INSERTED
                                   )
                SET @DELETECOUNT = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                     FROM   DELETED
                                   )

                IF @INSERTCOUNT > 0
                    AND @DELETECOUNT = 0 
                    BEGIN
                    -- Insert statements for trigger here
                        INSERT  INTO dbo.hdIssues
                             ( col1, col2)

                                SELECT  I.col1,
                                        I.col2                                     
                                FROM    INSERTED I          
                    END
                ELSE 
                    IF @INSERTCOUNT > 0
                        AND @DELETECOUNT > 0 
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT  INTO dbo.hdIssues
                                   ( col1, col2)
                                    SELECT  I.col1,
                                            I.col2 
                                    FROM    INSERTED I
                                            INNER JOIN DELETED D ON I.col1 = D.col1
                                    WHERE   I.col1 <> D.col1
                                            OR 
                                            I.col2 <> D.col2

                        END
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH 

            END CATCH
        END
    GO
```